# Minus and Plus Sign in jobs Process

Tags: process, job-control

These commands are running in the background:

```
foo@contoso ~ $ sleep 30 &
foo@contoso ~ $ sleep 60 &
foo@contoso ~ $ sleep 90 &
```

What is the minus and plus sign after running jobs process?

```
foo@contoso ~ $ jobs
[1]   Running                 sleep 30 &
[2]-  Running                 sleep 60 &
[3]+  Running                 sleep 90 &
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/559217/241265

Answer (score 27):

From `man jobs(1P)`:

> <current> The character '+' identifies the job that would be used as a default for the fg or bg utilities; this job can also be specified using  the
>                  job_id  %+  or "%%".  The character '−' identifies the job that would become the default if the current default job were to exit; this job
>                  can also be specified using the job_id %−. For other jobs, this field is a <space>.

Comment: How do I get the man page of `jobs`? Seriously, I have been looking for it quite a while: On my system, `man jobs` just popups the `builtin` man page; from bash's `help jobs` this exact piece of information is missing and in the end I googled for it and found this answer. However, I would love to have a real man page also for builtin commands.

Comment: @Daniel http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/jobs.1p.html